# Microdata/Schema.org/SEO: How to properly set a ContactPoint

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata

After adding microdata to a page, I usually go to: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/ to test it out and to make sure there's nothing missing.

I am getting the following error:

**"ContactPoint must be attached to a parent with a declared type"**

I am not sure what I am missing...?

**Sample HTML**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <p>
        <span itemprop="description">Webmaster</span>: 
        <span itemprop="name">Omar</span>
        <br/><a itemprop="url" href="https://plus.google.com/+Omar/">Profile</a>
    </p>

    <p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
        To contact me please email me at 
            <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:omar@somewhere.com">omar@somewhere.com</a>
            <meta itemprop="contactType" content="Webmaster"/>
            <meta itemprop="sameAs" content="https://plus.google.com/+OmarJuvera"/>
            <meta itemprop="availableLanguage" content="English"/>
            <meta itemprop="availableLanguage" content="Spanish"/>
            <meta itemprop="availableLanguage" content="Japanese"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(While Google’s Testing Tool reports this as an *error*, it’s not an actual error. It should be a warning instead. Your code is valid Microdata and you are correctly using the Schema.org vocabulary.)

1. You have two top-level items (a `Person` and a `ContactPoint`), i.e., they are not related in any way.
2. If you want to say that the `ContactPoint` is the contact point for the `Person`, then you need a property to connect these two items (the HTML-level nesting is not relevant here).
3. Looking at the defined properties for [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person), you can find the [`contactPoint` property](http://schema.org/contactPoint), which takes a `ContactPoint` as value and is defined as:

   > A contact point for a person or organization.

   So this property is appropriate for your case.
4. Add the `contactPoint` property to the `Person` item, referencing the `ContactPoint` item:

   ```html
   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
     …
     <p itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
     …
     </p>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: it worked, but now it's giving me another error >_<....:`The value provided for webmaster must be a valid contact type.` In schema.org's definition for http://schema.org/contactType is text. So I am under the impression that any value goes...Why the error?

Comment: @Omar: Yes, any text value goes, as far as Schema.org is concerned. However, Google has additional rules on top of that: the value should be one of the [listed values](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/customize/contact-points?&hl=en). Again, this is only a rule specific to Google’s Rich Snippet parsing. Not providing such a value is perfectly valid and fine, you might just don’t get a Google Rich Snippet then.

Comment: @Omar: If you don’t especially care about Google, but want to validate your Microdata/Schema.org, you should probably use a different tool as Google’s Testing Tool always reports Google-specific issues. See, for example, the question [Online Microdata parser](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13674/60).

Comment: It appears that Google got put to shame with this post, and COMPLETE changed the content of [listed values](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/customize/contact-points?&hl=en) and instead created a new page [corporate contacts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts) mentioning _...Additional contact types may be supported later.._ to tone down on their own demands to control the values of `contactType`