# Structured-Data > Microdata > Schema > Article > Author Itemscope > Properties > Google Validation Error

Tags: markup, schema.org, microdata

I am developing my own site locally. This is my first site so I am a relative 'noob'.

I have begun the process of marking up my site with the microdata format using the schema.org vocabulary.

I am using Google's structured data tester to test my microdata markup.

On a webpage I have marked up an article.

**THE PROBLEM**

I am getting errors for all `properties` for a `person itemscope` successfully connected to the `article itemscope`. It does not matter how the person is linked, whether as `author` or `creator` or otherwise.

For example, if I link a `person` to the `article` using the `author` property and try to then mark up their name with the `name` property, it gives a red error roughly like so:

> !
>   http://www.example.com/name:  Name

Where the property name is the cited in a url/property format, and where 'Name' is the property value I actually want.

If I then click on the error message, it says:

> The property http://www.example.com/name is not recognised by Google
>   for an object of type Thing.

It is otherwise:

- showing the other article properties fine; and
- creating an person-type property for the article fine (eg author, creator, etc); and
- creating name:value pairs for properties of the person (eg name).

But it just doesn't recognise the properties of the person.

**MARKUP SAMPLE**

Here is a sample of how I am marking it up:

```
<html>

...

<div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">

    <h1 itemprop="headline name">
        Awesome Things
    </h1>

    <div itemprop="articleBody">
        Blah blah blah  ... FLUFFY KITTENS ... blah blah blah ... DONUTS ... blah blah blah ... COFFEE!!! ...

        AUTHOR:                     
        <span itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemptype="https://schema.org/Person">
            <span itemprop="name">
                Joe Blogs-a-Lot
            </span>                 
        </span>

    </div>

...

</div>
</html>
```

**TRIED**

I have tried testing with alternate properties with person as an expected type (`author` and `creator`). Same result.

I have also tried wrapping person itemscope around the properties, and using `itemref` and `ID` to target the values. This works, but has the downside of adding those values to properties in common with the article. So, for example, the article gets the additional `name` value of `Joe Blogs-a-Lot` - which isn't correct.

**INVESTIGATIONS**

I have had a bit of a look-see but couldn't quite find a specific answer - which surprised me.

I did notice that there were reports of issues with the testing tool. For example, I note [this answer from the AWESOME CONTRIBUTOR in this area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341994/4806086), the mighty [@unor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor). If you see this, Unor, thanks for all the help you have provided to so many people here about this stuff. You rock.

**THE ACTUAL QUESTION**

Am I doing something dumb (a distinct possibility from past experience), or is this an issue with the tester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup sample contains a typo:

```html
itemptype="https://schema.org/Person"
```

should be

```html
itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"
```

Unfortunately, the Google Structured Data Testing Tool doesn’t report such errors. (And they shouldn’t have interpreted the property `name` as the URL `http://www.example.com/name`, because an item without a type could have a [proprietary item property name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute), which would not be a URL.)

---

On a side note: You [might want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112323/1591669) use `http` instead of `https` for the Schema.org URLs.